# Swap unused, high memory usage and swappiness at 100

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, memory-usage, swap

I'm running a server with a number of game servers on it.

My memory usage is very high, however there is almost no swap usage in comparison.

My swappiness is set to 100

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           125G        114G        1.6G        754M        9.6G        9.9G
Swap:          127G        889M        127G
```

fdisk output

```
Disk /dev/sda: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xeaabd0c6

Device     Boot   Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048     999423    997376   487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1001470 1000214527 999213058 476.5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1001472 1000214527 999213056 476.5G 8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 348.5 GiB, 374207414272 bytes, 730873856 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 128 GiB, 137388621824 bytes, 268337152 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

swapon -s

```
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/dm-1                               partition       134168572       958328  -1
```

Why isn't the swap getting used?

Comment: Why isn't the swap being used?

Comment: Do you see the server ever actually run out of RAM? ~1.6G is still a significant chunk. Also what are the applications that are running on this server? Are they Java apps? Also what does `swapon -s` show?

Comment: Some useful resources - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88693/why-is-swappiness-set-to-60-by-default & https://askubuntu.com/questions/103915/how-do-i-configure-swappiness.

Comment: It's hosting game servers.

Comment: That part I saw in your Q, can you be more specific, are they written in Java? I'm curious if there's a JVM involved. Typically the JVM has Xmx and Xms settings which can restrict it from going beyond.

Comment: Ark servers, Unreal engine mixed with steams server software, so should be c++

Comment: Why would it swap when there's still **9.9G available**? (That's more than many server has in total. )